# Atlassian Bamboo - Inject variable having '?' in string, possible encoding issue

Tags: powershell, variables, automation, bamboo, inject

I have a script task in powershell inline script in which i use

```
$text2 = "isApproved=$isApproved"
```

then i use,

```
Out-File -FilePath "${bamboo.build.working.directory}\repovar.properties" -InputObject $text2 -Append -Encoding utf8
```

`$isApproved` is determined in the script and can have value 0/1.

the properties file is showing proper key-value pair (`isApproved=0`). However, when i run the inject bamboo variable task, it injects a '?' symbol in the variable name

```
10-Aug-2020 05:17:58    key: [inject.?isApproved] value: [0] type: RESULT
```

It's a peculiar problem as it sometimes inject properly but sometimes doesn't. All other variables are injected in proper format.

When i remove the -Encoding utf8 in the cmdlet to default (utf8 with NoBOM), it then writes like this
`i s A p p r o v e d = 0` and bamboo injects like this

```
bamboo.inject._i_s_A_p_p_r_o_v_e_d
```

I have tried with batch script as well, i still see a '?'. Can anybody help me with an workaround?

If i switch to script file instead of inline script, can i still use the previous inject variables??

Comment: Is this powershell 5.1?  The default encoding is utf16.  Out-file -append can also mix different encodings in the same file.

Answer (score 0):

This is not well documented indeed - you need to replace dots with underscores, i.e. for a plan variable named your.plan.variable, which you would reference in a regular Bamboo task as ${bamboo.your.plan.variable}, the resp. PowerShell syntax for use within the Script task is $bamboo_your_plan_variable.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer from the Atlassian forum, here it is

```
Out-File -FilePath "${bamboo.build.working.directory}\repovar.properties" -InputObject $text2 -Append -Encoding ascii
```

Changing encoding to ASCII did the trick.